# joda LocalDateTime format to a custom format

Tags: java, json, datetime, jodatime

In my application there are multiple posts of a user with respective timestamps. Which I fetch & display in the UI.

time property in my Java class

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
private LocalDateTime postCreationTime;
```

the timestamp value which gets saved in the database is in this format `2015-08-15 03:04:52`

but when I fetch it from the db & send it via JSON to the UI, the process of JSON conversion the format changes to a JSON array

```
"postCreationTime":[2015,8,15,10,49,38,0]
```

now converting an array to a required time format `15 July 2015, 10:49 PM`
on the UI is a little tricky.

I am using Jackson library to serialize data into JSON

**I have two approaches in mind**

**A.** I save the post creation time in the db in `15 July 2015, 10:49 PM` format, which I am not sure is possible & also not a good practice

**B.** When I fetch n posts for a user I loop through all the posts & convert the timestamp into the required format. Which would definitely increase the latency.

Can anyone advice me what would be the best approach to handle this scenario?

Comment: moment.js is a great library to parse, format and manipulate dates in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks JB, could you please tell me how to avoid the conversion of the timestamp into a json array, why isn't the server sending the timestamp as is?

Comment: First of all, it's not a timestamp (but it should probably be one). It's a LocalDateTime. It can only be changed into a timestamp if you know the timezone used, when saving the post, to transform the current date into a LocalDateTime. I would store the post creation time as an Instant. You can then choose whatever timezone you want (the user timezone, the server timezone, or UTC) to transform the timezone into a String. Assuming you use Jackson to transform objects to JSON, there is a Joda-time module, that you can configure (or you could create yours), to choose another format.

Comment: But whatever format you choose, it's possible to transform it and format it using a good library like moment.js.

Comment: Which library do you use to serialize objects into json?